# Binding must have optional type Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting this error and I cannot figure out how to fix it. I have went through all of the answers on here but nothing I try is working. Here is my code:

```
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error ) -> Void in

            var title = ""

            if (error == nil) {

                if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark){

                    var subThoroughfare:String = ""
                    var thoroughfare:String = ""

                    if p.subThoroughfare != nil{

                        subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare
                    }

                    if p.thoroughfare != nil{

                        thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare
                    }

                    title = "\(subThoroughfare) \(thoroughfare)"
                }
            }

            if title == ""{

                title = "Added \(NSDate())"

            }
```

The error is on line:

```
                if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark){
```

Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLPlacemark'

Comment: Not bashing or anything, but this should go up there with `Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, in the "Pantheon of Self-Explanatory Console Messages That Tell You Exactly What's Wrong With Your Code (TM)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You report the error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CLPlacemark'

This is because you're calling `CLPlacemark(placemark: CLPlacemark)`, but that's not returning an optional. So it's complaining that you're using `if let` syntax, which is only valid with optionals.

But you really don't want to do that forced unwrapping of `placemarks`, and I'd suggest you eliminate that `!` altogether. Furthermore, given that in Swift 2, the `placemarks` is now a `[CLPlacemark]?`, and you can eliminate the cast altogether, thereby simplifying that `if` statement:

```
if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
    let subThoroughfare = placemark.subThoroughfare ?? ""
    let thoroughfare    = placemark.thoroughfare    ?? ""

    title = "\(subThoroughfare) \(thoroughfare)"
}
```

Note, you can simplify the `thoroughfare` and `subThoroughfare` implementations, too, as shown above.

Answer (score -2):

This works.

if  let p = placemarks?[0]

Comment: But it will crash with an "out of bounds" error if the array is empty. That's why Rob uses `.first` instead of `[0]` in his answer.